# same url path for subcategories and posts

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a client wordpress site where the client has requested to keep blog categories url as before.

```
http://example.com/recipie/
```

Now he wants to add subcategories and default wordpress make the url for subcategories as

```
http://example.com/recipie/soups/
```

problems is the posts url is also like this

```
http://example.com/recipie/a-sample-post/
```

and hence the subcategories aren't working.

I have tried opening

```
http://example.com/soups/
```

and this uses archive.php as template. but i really need this

```
http://example.com/recipie/soups/
```

to work and keep the posts url intact. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question. Here is the answer for this.

First and foremost got post-> category list page and then open subcategory and select the parent category and save the subcategory.

you will get your category URL like

```
http://example.com/recipie/soups/
```

Second thing go to Setting->Permalinks  select sample post and place

```
%category% before %sample-post%
```

Now you will get your URL like

```
http://example.com/recipie/a-sample-post/
```

try this steps, I hope it will work.

Comment: I am Sorry. if my question was confusing. but http://example.com/recipie/soups/ shows 404. And http://example.com/recipie/a-sample-post/ is working fine. I needed the http://example.com/recipie/soups/ to show subcategories posts.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to `Settings->Permalinks` and choose  `Custom Structure` option.
You just need to add this in permalinks as `/%category%/%postname%/`. Please in the screenshot.

For recipie:

```
http://localhost/wp_woocommerce/recipie/hello-world/
```

recipie/soups:

```
http://localhost/wp_woocommerce/recipie/soups/a-sample-post/
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Ankur Singh, Please follow these steps.

Comment: I already have this @Gufran Hasan. My posts are working but subcategories pages aren't.

Comment: I am Sorry, if my question was confusing. but example.com/recipie/soups shows 404. And example.com/recipie/a-sample-post is working fine. I needed the example.com/recipie/soups to show subcategories posts. I have set category-base as dot (.) as well.

Comment: I think you need to list all the posts of subcategories. for example.com/recipie/soups Right?

Comment: yes. i want this url example.com/recipie/soups to list all "soups" on it using my template. but its querying a post name "soups" and hence generating 404 error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171741/discussion-between-ankur-singh-and-gufran-hasan).